# How to retrieve environment variable of command after run

Tags: go, environment-variables

I'm running a simple command via `exec.Command` in Go. Now I want to know if it is possible to get all the environment variables of this process.

Cause I can set them using this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash ./script.sh")
cmd.Dir = filepath.Join(s.Path, "..")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Env = []string{"MY_VAR=some_value"}
err := cmd.Run()
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if this would also work for Windows/MacOS/Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

I hate saying "it is not possible" because there are always *some* ways to do things like this (for example, read `/proc/.../environ` on Linux, do some complicated `ReadProcessMemory` poking in Windows, etc.). But, it is not intended to do this and there is no portable solution for it either.

Environment variables are local to a process, and upon process creation, the parent process' environment variables are inherited or whatever you set. But they are not designed as mechanism to send data back to the parent process.

If you need to communicate information from your child to your parent, there is a number of ways to do so:

- You could send data to `stdout` and capture it in the parent
- You could use a pipe/socket and pass the corresponding handle as a commandline parameter
- You could use shared memory/a memory-mapped file
- You could use an actual file at a known location (not recommended)

Comment: The short answer is enough as OPs question shows a fundamental misconception on how environment variables work and are intended to be used.

Comment: @cherrydt thanks for the detailed explanation. I did not know that it was designed like this. I'm building a CLI in Go that needs the possibility to run user defined scripts, but I would like those scripts to run in the same process (so that they can share environment variables).

Comment: In case of bash scripts, you could try wrapping them in another script which saves all environment variables to a file at the end (or outputs them or otherwise communicates them back to the parent) and then the parent can update its own environment variables accordingly.