Why does exec.Cmd.Wait trigger when executing a loop command like `rollup -w` in Golang?
I'm using Go's exec.Command to run rollup -w, which watches for file changes. However, I noticed that exec.Cmd.Wait() is triggered immediately after executing this command.
Why does this happen? Shouldn't Wait() wait for the command to finish its execution instead of triggering instantly?
Here’s a snippet of my code:
func runCommand(cmd *exec.Cmd) error {
    outpipe, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    errpipe, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    readPipe := func(pipe io.ReadCloser) {
        defer wg.Done()
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(pipe)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()
            printProc(line)
        }
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go readPipe(outpipe)
    wg.Add(1)
    go readPipe(errpipe)
    
    // i expect this code will never reach this line
    if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    wg.Wait()
    return nil
}

i call it with rollup:
func roll() error {
    cmdRoll := exec.Command("npm", "run", "roll")
    printProc("running roll command")

    if err := runCommand(cmdRoll); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    printProc("roll command executed successfully")
    return nil
}

npm run roll : "roll": "rimraf build && rollup --config rollup.config.ts --configPlugin @rollup/plugin-typescript -w"

I think you are correct. According to the documentation Wait waits for the command to exit and waits for any copying from stdout or stderr to complete.
Is it possible that rollup main process starts -> spawns child process that does the watching behavior -> exits main process -> cmd.Wait() is called?
Rebuild the bundle when its source files change on disk.
From rollup documentation:
Note: While in watch mode, the ROLLUP_WATCH environment variable will be set to "true" by Rollup's command line interface and can be checked by other processes.
Could you check this env variable?

Wait is how you wait for a command to finish, there is no other way to know when it completes, and must always be called for child processes.  Any of the exec helper methods which run synchronously just call Wait for you.

As for why does it reach the Wait at all, what do you think it wouldn’t? There is no blocking code before that line.

@JimB I think the only blocking code would be the call to wg.Wait() which comes after the if statement.
if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
return err
}

@BradleyMarques: cmd.Wait() is blocking, it blocks until the process exits (what would be the point of it otherwise?). The wg.Wait() blocks until the goroutines return to ensure they have printed everything before the outer function returns.

I am sure I understand. I am referring to your previous comment saying there is no blocking code before that line referring to the call to cmd.Wait @Jim

"While in watch mode, the ROLLUP_WATCH environment variable will be set to "true" by Rollup's command line interface and can be checked by other processes. Could you check this env variable? "  I think that must be available for the commands it runs.  A process can't change its  parent process's environment variables, and there's no easy way to obtain a process's env vars either (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583816/how-to-retrieve-environment-variable-of-command-after-run)

Your setup is correct. I suspect what's happening here is npm run roll :
starts -> spawns child process that does the watching behavior -> exits main process -> cmd.Wait()

Just as Bradley suggested above. In that case the semantics of what you're trying to achieve changes.
